# how break loop in a while statement using a command receive from the server

Tags: c#, while-loop, tcp

Im having a problem breaking in while loop statement with a command coming from the server. Since i cant get anymore message coming from the server while in the loop. I also tried to read the stream and try to get a message but it fails as you can see in my code. Is there any way to catch a message coming from the server while in that loop?

```
    public void Connect()
    {
        clientSocket.Connect("localhost", 4200);
        serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

        byte[] outStream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(User + "$");
        serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
        serverStream.Flush();

        Thread ctThread = new Thread(getMessage);
        ctThread.Start();
    }

    public async void getMessage()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
            int buffsize = 0;
            byte[] inStream = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
            buffsize = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
            serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffsize);
            string rData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream);
            readData = "" + rData;
            readData = readData.Replace("\0", "");

            switch (readData)
            {
                case ("Receive"):
                    break;
                case ("Overview"):
                    Boolean lBreak = false;
                    while (!lBreak)
                    {
                        BinaryFormatter binFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                        serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                        pictureBox1.Image = (Image)binFormatter.Deserialize(serverStream);
                        Thread ccb = new Thread(starter);
                        ccb.Start();

                        //int closer = 0;
                        //byte[] relay = new byte[clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
                       // closer = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
                        //serverStream.Read(relay, 0, closer);
                        //string terminate = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(relay);
                        //readDataa = "" + terminate;
                        //readDataa = readDataa.Replace("\0", "");

                        //getMessage();

                        //switch (readDataa)
                        //{
                        //    case "stopOverview":
                        //        lBreak = true;
                        //        serverStream.Flush();
                        //        break;
                        //}

                        //if(lBreak == true)
                        //{
                        //    serverStream.Flush();
                        //    break;
                        //}
                    } 
                    break;
                case ("125"):
                    Application.Run(new Form3());
                    break;
                case ("Return"):

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `but it fails as you can see in my code.` I can't see it unfortunately. Can you point me to the relevant bit and explain why it fails?

Comment: when i receive the Overview command it will start the while loop. i would like  to break that loop with another command coming from the server.

Comment: You should save the reference to the thread you are creating in the first command and stop it.

Comment: @Igal23 the problem here is it can be only break with a request from the server and i cant receive anymore request within that loop. does multi open socket can help?